# Jetty on Heroku: how to tell in code if https was used

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, https, jetty

I have some servlets running in Jetty, deployed on Heroku, handling POST requests.

Some, but not all, POST requests MUST come over https.  Whether or not a request should be forced to be on https depends on the http body of the POST request.

I need to figure out, from inside the servlet, whether the incoming request used https (SSL) or not, so that I can send the appropriate response.  However, nothing I have tried seems to work.

I tried the obvious `HttpServletRequest.getProtocol()` but that apparently returns the same constant whether the protocol was `http` or `https`.

I tried `HttpServletRequest.isSecure()` however that is returning false even though my test request was sent to a url starting with https://

When I call `HttpUtils.getRequestURL( HttpServletRequest ).toString();`  I get an apparrently reconstructed url that starts with "http://" even though my test request was sent to a url starting with "https://"

According to the post "[Enforce HTTPS with Embedded Jetty on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564638/enforce-https-with-embedded-jetty-on-heroku)" heroku has some load balancers, and I should get the value of the "x-forwarded-proto" header.  That header is blank.

FYI I am using the default SSL endpoint provided by the heroku api -- I am not using their SSL Endpoint extension, because this url is not being loaded in a browser (so I don't need a custom domain in the url).

Can anyone tell me how to tell if HTTPS was used in the incoming request?

Comment: Have you tried using HttpServletRequest.getScheme() to identify whether the request was sent via HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Heroku, but if you're programmatically configuring Jetty (as opposed to using the XML configuration), you likely need to add the `SecureRequestCustomizer` to your `HttpConfiguration`. It sets the secure flag on the requests, as well as setting the scheme to HTTPS. You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362245/programatically-configure-ssl-for-jetty-9-embedded), but briefly:

```
final HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setSecurePort(httpsPort);
final ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
    new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
httpConnector.setPort(httpPort);
server.addConnector(httpConnector);

final HttpConfiguration httpsConfig = new HttpConfiguration(httpConfig);
httpsConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); // !!!
final HttpConnectionFactory httpsFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig);
final SslConnectionFactory sslFactory = new SslConnectionFactory(sslCtx,
    httpsFactory.getProtocol());
final ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
    sslFactory, httpsFactory);
httpsConnector.setPort(httpsPort);
server.addConnector(httpsConnector);
```

I too found it rather surprising that this poorly documented step was necessary.

Comment: Oh how I wish I could give you more than one upvote!